# Congratulations! Software Recommendations is graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Software Recommendations recently met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: After less than 600 days too.  That's quicker than many beta sites.

Comment: *You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network* That's good for the site!

Comment: Yea for us!  Good job everyone!

Comment: @JanDoggen I have never understood why it is preferable to close a question than migrating it to a beta SE.

Comment: @franckDernoncourt mods can migrate to beta sites, but only in certain conditions

Comment: @Franck Two different reasons. One is that sometimes a new beta site isn't prepared to receive questions from larger traffic sites - a mixture of the different sorts of askers and the volume can actually wreak havoc on the normal growth of the site when it's just plopped out rather than organically received. The other is that sometimes a question's in terrible form when originally asked elsewhere - migrating it to a new place and forcing them to do the heavy work on fixing up the question is less than ideal.

Comment: So how come http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations seems to say SR is still in beta?

Comment: @IraBaxter It's a bug we're lookin' at.

Comment: You didn't say much about the colour theme this site would get!

Comment: On reading this post more carefully, I note the phrase *cleared for graduation*.  Is this site still in Beta, or not?

Comment: @IraBaxter it's already graduated; there's no "beta" text added to the site name on main page.

Answer (score 15):

Wonderful! Well done everyone :-)

Most people expected us to fail. It is historical, we have proved that recommendations can work on Stack Exchange if done right. I hope [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) will follow that path.

We can expect to get more questions/askers redirected to us, which is a good thing.

It might also be a good time to think about design/logo ideas, even though professional Stack designers are the ones who will ultimately decide and work on it.

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to extend a huge thank you to the community and my fellow moderators, with special thanks to the prolific flaggers out there - you know who you are. Together we've deleted more than 700 posts, the vast majority low quality answers. We couldn't haved survived without that. Thank you, unnamed flaggers.

I'll be badgering a few of you to stand in that election that's coming up ;)

Comment: That's a lot of teasing.

Comment: @Firelord don't you even *think* of renaming your profile to "unnamed" now! For compensation, I promise to not rename mine to "flaggers" :)