# When's the election coming?

Tags: support, graduation, election

[Congratulations! Software Recommendations is graduating!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating) mentions that "soon" there will be an election for diamond mods. I'm looking forward to that! But it's been several months with no sign. Over on ELL, we actually got the "congratulations" post **after** our first election finished.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your election will be starting on Monday, November 30th.

When we first made the announcement, the plan was to run down the remaining runs of elections for the remaining sites (Japanese, Music, and Software Recommendations). But then the system for design independent graduation we used... turned up a lot more bugs than we expected.

Fixing most all of them (which was done by ultimately changing the process we're using to do design-independent graduation) took us basically through mid-October to fully implement. We wanted a week to observe how the new process worked out, and so the first election was Japanese, scheduled on November 2nd. Then we scheduled Music to start on November 9th. We did not want to start an election that crosses through US Thanksgiving, so that left starting this week as a no-go - and why the next available date is November 30th.

Comment: Now going on at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election